# Xcode: Automatic (Permanent) Breakpoint on malloc_error_break?

Tags: xcode, gdb, breakpoints, lldb

Is it possible to set an automatic (or permanent) breakpoint on `malloc_error_break` under Xcode? (If its in Xcode and I missed it, please point it out). I want it to work everywhere under Xcode - from GDB to LLDB, to old and new projects. I would really like it to work on device, but that might be stretch ([it appears something is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396907/xcode-guard-malloc-and-on-device-debugging-libgmalloc-dylib-image-not-found) with malloc guard on device).

I was thinking `.lldbinit` might be helpful, but LLDB kind of kills that idea. It appears LLDB does not honor breakpoints set in `.lldbinit` (according to `breakpoint list`) (http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html). LLDB also disregards breakpoints in `.lldbinit-Xcode` (thanks Rob).

`.gdbinit` might also be useful, but we will likely run into the bug discussed at [Unable to set pending breakpoints in .gdbinit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078313/unable-to-set-pending-breakpoints-in-gdbinit). This is Apple, and they have a completely broken QA process, so I don't expect it to be fixed.

To summarize, the following does not work on this Mac (MacBook Pro, 10.8) and Xcode (4.5.2):

```
riemann: jwalton$ cat ~/.lldbinit
# http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html
# Not honored by LLDB
breakpoint set --name malloc_error_break
# Shot in the dark since the previous is not honored
breakpoint set pending --name malloc_error_break
riemann: jwalton$ cat ~/.gdbinit 
set breakpoint pending on
set breakpoint malloc_error_break
set breakpoint pending auto
```

EDIT (2013/02/07): Also see [lldb equivalent of .gdbinit and future break?](http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2013/Feb/msg00067.html).

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your gdb breakpoint, the Mac OS X gdb is a little different than the generic FSF gdb, you should be fine with just `b malloc_error_break` to have a permanent breakpoint there or worst case use `fb malloc_error_break` (an Apple-gdb specific `future-break` command that makes it explicit).

With lldb in Xcode 4.5 there was a bug that breakpoints set in the `.lldbinit` file were not added.  Not so much a bug as a design shortcoming, really, breakpoints are added to a *target* and when the `.lldbinit` file is being read, lldb doesn't have a target set up yet.  I think Greg Clayton fixed that in the svn repository lldb sources a couple of months ago, creating a placeholder for applying settings like this that are installed in any newly-created Targets from that point on.  With the svn lldb sources, putting `br s -n malloc_error_break` in your `.lldbinit` should work fine.

Comment: thanks. "With the svn lldb sources..." - there's no telling what will break on Apple platforms. The platform is fragile, and not like Linux/GDB or Windows/WinDbg. I'm afraid to try it.

Comment: I know it’s been a while, but which SVN revision of LLDB are you referring to? The version of LLDB that—at the time of this writing—ships with Xcode does **not** appear to include that patch—Xcode version in this case is 5.0.2 (5A3005), LLDB version is lldb-300.2.53.

Answer (score 3):

### UPDATE

There is an easy way to set up a permanent, all-projects breakpoint in Xcode.

Open up any project.  Go to the Breakpoints navigator.  Create a symbolic breakpoint on `malloc_error_break`.  Then, right-click the breakpoint in the navigator, and from the pop-up menu, choose Move Breakpoint To > User.  Xcode applies User breakpoints to all projects.

See [step 2 of this blog post](http://qwan.org/2013/06/18/how-to-snatch-the-error-code-from-the-trap-frame-in-xcode/) for a video.

### ORIGINAL

LLDB has its own init file, which is called… (drumroll please)… `.lldbinit`.  You can set the breakpoint there too.  The “Session 415 - Debugging with LLDB” video from [WWDC 2012](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) discusses this file in depth starting at 29m43s.  You can even make a `.lldbinit-Xcode` file that LLDB will load only when it's running under Xcode.

I don't have any advice for you regarding the GDB pending breakpoint problem.

Comment: Thanks Rob. It appears LLDB does not honor the breakpoint specified in `.lldbinit` (according to `breakpoint list`). Its Apple. What do you expect other than broken software?

Comment: As I explained in my answer, this is a known limitation of lldb in Xcode 4.5.  It will be fixed in the next release.