# How to solve the ** 0_abort_with_playload ** Error in ios 10.2.1.

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode8, ios10

I try to run the application in my ipad(V-10.2.1) and also iphone(V-10.1). when i run the application, it come build success and installing, once the launch page comes in my ipad or iphone it crash and freeze the screen and it show below error screen. i cant able to debug or log my Program.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfUoP.png)

Comment: I reboot the phone it not working. and i uninstall the application and run it no use. can you give me the other solution.

Comment: all the answers and discussions can be found on the above thread, and allso this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396907/xcode-guard-malloc-and-on-device-debugging-libgmalloc-dylib-image-not-found  I can not however give you any more answers than those posted

Comment: ya Thank you sneak i got it. its work fine

Comment: now i hide this Guard Malloc, if any issue will happen in future?

Comment: No problem, As long as it works there shouldnt be any issue, I have not investigated it. Please upvote my comment if it solved your question :)